# Angular filter is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use Angular filter under `ng-repeat`

Here is my code:

```
<ul id="testDiv2" class="dropdownH">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Keyword Filter" data-ng-model="search.category.category_name">
  <li data-ng-repeat="category in categories track by $index | filter: search.category.category_name" 
      data-ng-click="selectCategory($index)">
    <div class="colony pull-left">
      <span>{{category.category_name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <input type="radio" name="tag" />
      <label></label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above code is not working. But if I remove `track by $index` then it is working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Data is displayed but when you type in the input, filter is not getting applied. Is that the problem?

Comment: yes. data is showing. when filter is not getting applied

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: no .. Sorry no error

Comment: if i remove track by $index then it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

i need to use

```
<li data-ng-repeat="category in categories  | filter: search.category.category_name track by $index" data-ng-click="selectCategory($index)"
```

Comment: yes problem was track by, i was upto it after making plunker, any ways great to hear you have solved

Answer (score 2):

You have problem with track by expression , use it after the filter

for example use

```
data-ng-repeat="category in categories  | filter:search track by $index"
```

**Working Demo :**

```js
angular.module("test",[]).
controller("testController",function($scope){
$scope.categories = [{category_name:'abc'},{category_name:'cde'}];

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" >
<ul id="testDiv2" ng-controller="testController" class="dropdownH">
<input type="text" placeholder="Keyword Filter" data-ng-model="search">
<li data-ng-repeat="category in categories  | filter:search track by $index" data-ng-click="selectCategory($index)">
 <div class="colony pull-left"><span>{{category.category_name}}</span></div>
                                                        <div class="pull-right"><input type="radio" name="tag" /><label></label></div>

</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: could you provide a plunkr ? or be more clear about the problem?

Comment: working demo is provided now, but i think you have also figured it out